# Visit specific page after click on background firebase push notification

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, push-notification, ionic2

I am using firebase ionic push notification
`import { Push, PushObject, PushOptions} from '@ionic-native/push';`
`

```
      const pushObject: PushObject = this.push.init(options);
      pushObject.on('notification').subscribe((notification: any) => {
          if(notification.background){
            alert(JSON.stringify(notification));
                this.navCtrl.push('DetailPage', {
                  item: notification.additionalData
                });
            }
      });

      pushObject.on('registration').subscribe((registration: any) => {
         this.storage.get('isDeviceRegistered')
              .then((isDeviceRegistered) => {
                  if(!isDeviceRegistered){
                     this.registerDevice(registration.registrationId , this.token);
                     console.log(JSON.stringify(registration.registrationId));
                     this.storage.set('FireBaseRegID', registration.registrationId);
                  }
                  else{
                    console.log('Device Already Registered');
                  }
              });
      });

  pushObject.on('error').subscribe(error => alert('Error with Push plugin' + error));
  }`
```

But inside the on notification after getting notification I am not able to redirect to `DetailPage`, I am successfully getting notification object while alerting the value but unable to redirect to a particular page.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried ``router.navigate()`` ?

Comment: any errors in console?

Comment: @suraj-rao no errors in console

Comment: @cruelengine , I haven't tried with angular's router.navigate, not quite sure to use angular routing instead of ionic based push , pop routing sytsem